# Error with taking inputs all at once , when Using multiple classes and works fine in single class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, java.util.scanner

If I use just one class it works perfect but when I am using multiple classes, I am facing an issue where ,When I am giving the input as whole as a batch (copy paste) it doesn't work (still waits for some more input and does nothing), but when I give each input manually it works perfect.

So, this problem started when I introduced a new class so I guess there is something wrong with the class or inheritance when utilizing with the Scanner class.

Note : this is for my college elab, so I can't use files over here.

codeWithSingleClass -Works perfect

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        int nooftestCases=scanner.nextInt();

        while(nooftestCases>0) {
            int n,k;
            int[] array = new int[20];
            int sumWithOutRemoval=0 , sumWithRemoval=0;
            n = scanner.nextInt();
            k = scanner.nextInt();
            sumWithOutRemoval = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                sumWithOutRemoval += array[i];
            }
            if (k == 0) {
                double finalAns = (double) sumWithOutRemoval / n;
                System.out.println(String.format("%.6f", finalAns));
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
                        if (array[i] < array[j]) {
                            int temp = array[i];
                            array[i] = array[j];
                            array[j] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
                sumWithRemoval = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
                    sumWithRemoval += array[i];
                }
                double finalAns = (double) (sumWithRemoval / (n - (2 * k)));
                System.out.println(String.format("%.6f", finalAns));
            }
            nooftestCases--;
        }
    }
}
```

codeWithMultipleClasses-hasIssues

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Sample {

    static int n,k;
    static int[] array = new int[20];
    static int sumWithOutRemoval , sumWithRemoval;

    public void getDetails(){
        Scanner scanner2=new Scanner(System.in);
        n = scanner2.nextInt();
        k = scanner2.nextInt();
        sumWithOutRemoval = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner2.nextInt();
            sumWithOutRemoval += array[i];
        }
    }
    public void displayDetails(){
        if (k == 0) {
            double finalAns = (double) sumWithOutRemoval / n;
            System.out.println(String.format("%.6f", finalAns));
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
                    if (array[i] < array[j]) {
                        int temp = array[i];
                        array[i] = array[j];
                        array[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            sumWithRemoval = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
                sumWithRemoval += array[i];
            }
            double finalAns = (double) (sumWithRemoval / (n - (2 * k)));
            System.out.println(String.format("%.6f", finalAns));
        }
    }
}
public class Main extends Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        int nooftestCases=scanner.nextInt();
        Sample objname= new Sample();
        while(nooftestCases>0) {
            objname.getDetails();
            objname.displayDetails();
            nooftestCases--;
        }
    }
}
```

My inputs are

```
5
5 0
2 9 -10 25 1
5 1
2 9 -10 25 1
5 1
2 9 -10 25 1
5 0
2 9 -10 25 1
5 1
2 9 -10 25 1
```

expected output

```
5.400000
4.000000
4.000000
5.400000
4.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two `Scanner` instances; they're mocking up the input steam. If we change the code to pass the `Scanner scanner` into the `Sample` object, and use that, instead of the `scanner2`, all is fine.

I.e. something like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int nooftestCases = scanner.nextInt();
Sample objname = new Sample(scanner);
```

And:

```
class Sample {
    ...

    private final Scanner scanner;

    public Sample(Scanner scanner) {
        this.scanner = scanner;
    }

    public void getDetails() {
        n = scanner.nextInt();
        k = scanner.nextInt();
        sumWithOutRemoval = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            sumWithOutRemoval += array[i];
        }
    }
...
```

---

As an aside, there are more opportunities for improvement on this code. Formatting would be one of them, particularly when posting on Stack Overflow. Something else that specifically hurts my eyes is the `static` fields (not to mention their unspecified scope). This would be suspect for making algorithmic code like this work well in a broader application. And what are `k` and `v` (suggesting more-descriptive names).

Comment: thanks alot sir , your solution worked . And I am a begginer in java , and i would surely improve my code structure and format as you said.